# Plotting eigenvalues

Tags: differential-equations, eigenvalues

I am trying to reproduce figure 10 in the linked [paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6134060/pdf/41598_2018_Article_31777.pdf). The authors have used Matlab bvp4c function to find multiple solutions for the system of ODE and then carried out the stability.

Here is my try,

```
s = 1; beta = 0.1; M = 0.2; Pr = 1; max = 7;

pfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{f'''[x] + f[x]*f''[x] + 
      beta*(1 - f'[x]^2) + M^2*(1 - f'[x]) == 0, 
    1/Pr*T''[x] + f[x]*T'[x] == 0, f[0] == s, f'[0] == L1, T[0] == 1, 
    f'[xmax] == 1, T[xmax] == 0}, {f, T}, {x, 0, xmax}, {L1}]; (*Eqs 8,9 and 10*)

part[l_List, n_Integer] := Part[l, n];

qfun = ParametricNDSolveValue[{F'''[x] + part[pfun[L1], 1][2]*F''[x] +
       D[part[pfun[L1], 1][2], x, x]*
       F[x] - (2*beta*D[part[pfun[L1], 1][2], x] + M^2 - g1)*F'[x] == 
     0, 1/Pr*G''[x] + part[pfun[L1], 1][2] + G'[x] + 
      D[part[pfun[L1], 2][2], x]*F[x] + g1*G[x] == 0, F[0] == 0, 
    F'[0] == 0, G[0] == 0, F'[xmax] == 0, G[xmax] == 0}, {F, G}, {x, 
    0, xmax}, {L1, g1}]; (*Eqs 22, 23 and 34 using solution from 8,9 and 10*)
```

Here the part function is calling the solutions from the original system of ODEs.
The `NDSolve` is even unable to find the one solution, so I cannot proceed further. 
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

If you write

```
s = 1; beta = 0.1; M = 0.2; Pr = 1; xmax = 7; (* note xmax, not max *)
```

then

```
pfun = 
  ParametricNDSolveValue[
    {f'''[x] + f[x]*f''[x] + beta*(1 - f'[x]^2) + M^2*(1 - f'[x]) == 0, 
     1/Pr*T''[x] + f[x]*T'[x] == 0, 
      f[0] == s, f'[0] == L1, T[0] == 1, f'[xmax] == 1, T[xmax] == 0}, 
    {f, T}, {x, 0, xmax}, {L1}];
```

will return something that will plot:

```
With[{L1 = 10.},
  Plot[Evaluate[Through[pfun[L1][x]]], {x, 0, xmax},
    PlotRange -> {-1, All},
    AxesOrigin -> {0, -1}]]
```

[image: plot]

However, in the case of next system of ODE's, I find I need rewrite your code to

```
With[{L1 = 10.},
  pf1 = pfun[L1][[1]]; pf2 = pfun[L1][[2]];
  qfun =
    ParametricNDSolveValue[{F'''[x] + pf1[2]*F''[x] + 
      D[pf1[x], x, x][[0]][2]*F[x] - (2*beta*D[pf1[x], x][[0]][2] + 
        M^2 - g1)*F'[x] == 0, 
      1/Pr*G''[x] + pf1[2] + G'[x] + D[pf2[x], x][[0]][2]*F[x] + g1*G[x] == 0,
      F[0] == 0, F'[0] == 0, G[0] == 0, F'[xmax] == 0, G[xmax] == 0}, 
     {F, G}, {x, 0, xmax}, {g1}]];
```

and then `qfun` can be plotted for `L1 = 10.` and `g1 = 2` with this code:

```
With[{g1 = 2},
  Plot[Evaluate[Through[qfun[g1][x]]], {x, 0, xmax},
    PlotRange -> All,
    AxesOrigin -> {0, -120}]]
```

[image: plot]

#### Update

Looking the conditions placed on `F` by OP equations and the resulting plot, I conclude that `F` is identically zero for all `x` in the domain `{0, 7}`. This allows a much simpler solution for `G` to be developed, from which is it rather easy to write a function that will plot `g` over the given domain for and given pair of the parameters `L1` and `g1`. I present that function in this update.

```
GfunPlot[l1_, g1_] :=
  Block[{pf1, Gfun},
    pf1 = pfun[l1][[1]];
    Gfun =
      ParametricNDSolveValue[
        {1/Pr*G''[x] + pf1[2] + G'[x] + g*G[x] == 0,
         G[0] == 0, G[xmax] == 0},
        G, {x, 0, xmax}, g];
    Plot[Gfun[g1][x], {x, 0, xmax},
      PlotRange -> All,
      PlotLabel -> 
        Style[Row[{G[x], ":  L1 = ", l1, ", g1 = ", g1}], Black, 14]]]
```

And here is a sample set of plots.

```
GraphicsGrid[Table[GfunPlot[l1, g1], {l1, {5, 10}}, {g1, {2, 4}}], 
  ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image: grid]

This is really all the information that can be extracted from the OP's formulation of the problem. The conditions imposed on `F` constricts the system's behavior severely.

Comment: First of Thx. I am looking for the plot `g1` vs `L1`, as given in the paper (see Fig 10 on page 7)

Comment: @zhk that looks to be essentially the first plot, at least from rough visual inspection.

Comment: @CATrevillian The results plotted here are for `f, F, T` and `G` vs `x`.

Comment: @zhk. But you formulated your question with `g1` and `L1` as parameters of systems set up to find `f`, `T`, `F` and `G` as functions of `x`. I can only work with what you post on this site. I am not going read your reference material and work out the math for you. I very likely wouldn't even understand the reference. I'm here to help people with Mathematica,  no solve their math or physics problems. There are other SE sites for that.